Record vs RecordMeasurement
Can someone explain what is the difference between Record() and RecordMeasurement() on dotnet System.Diagnostics.Metrics?
The docs says that the former “Record the Gauge current value” while the latter “Records a measurement by notifying all listeners MeterObjects that are listening to this instrument”, but I am having a hard understand that difference.
